# AVAudio Player Not stopped

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"Breath"
                                     ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSError *error;
breathPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    breathPlayer.delegate = self;
    [breathPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```

And Here i Stop my player in Function

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([self isTouch:touch WithinBoundsOf:MouthArea]) {
        BreathImg.center = MouthArea.center;
        NSLog(@"Touch Correct");
        [breathPlayer play];
        [breathPlayer setNumberOfLoops:1];
    } else {
        [breathPlayer stop];
    }
}
```

Player is not stop. it acts like Pause

Comment: you can add a line `breathPlayer = nil` after `[breathPlayer stop];` to stop the player.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the apple documentation for the [`stop` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/stop). In fact:

> The stop method does not reset the value of the currentTime property
>   to 0. In other words, if you call stop during playback and then call
>   play, playback resumes at the point where it left off.

You can just add

```
breathPlayer.currentTime = 0.0;
```

after your `[breathPlayer stop];` line to accomplish what you want.